# Net-SNMP over TCP?

Tags: linux, snmp

Is it possible to get Net-SNMP running over TCP instead of UDP?

The daemon program can be configured at the termiinnal to listen for TCP connections with:

`snmpd tcp:1161`

However, there are no flags for the `snmpget` to use TCP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think snmpget also supports that.  There are some common features described on the snmpcmd(1M) man page that they don't bother repeating on all the individual command pages.

```
 Agent Specification
     The agent specification (see SYNOPSIS) takes the form:

     [transport-specifier:]transport-address

     At its simplest, the agent specification consists of a host-
     name or an IPv4 address in the standard, "dotted quad" nota-
     tion. In this case, communication will  be  attempted  using
     UDP/IPv4  to  port  161  of  the  given host. Otherwise, the
     transport-address  part  of  the  specification  is   parsed
     according to the following table:

     <transport-specifier>   <transport-address> format

     udp                     hostname[:port]

     Note that transport-specifier strings  are  case-insensitive
     so  that,  for example, "tcp" and "TCP" are equivalent. Here
     are some examples, along with interpretations:

     myhost:161

     Perform query using UDP/IPv4 datagrams  sent  to  myhost  on
     port  161.  The  :161  is redundant here because that is the
     default SNMP port.

     udp:myhost

     Identical to the previous specification. The udp: is  redun-
     dant here because UDP/IPv4 is the default transport.
```